# AttributeError: __exit__ when use `with` statement

Tags: python, exception, sqlalchemy, yield, with-statement

I followed with this [guide](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#session-frequently-asked-questions) to write a `session_scope` for SQLAlchemy. When I run the code, I am getting an `AttributeError` exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tuanchauict/workspace/opla-manga/python-server-non-django/demo.py", line 56, in <module>
    with session_scope() as s:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

My code is:

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False)

def session_scope():
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
    finally:
        session.close()

with session_scope() as session:  # <=== error here
    pass
```

I am running Python 3.4 on Mac OS 10.10.

Comment: You forgot to put the `@contextmanager` decorator on your function (as shown in the code on that page).